# How to resolve : AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformer' object has no attribute 'transform'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pipeline, sentence-transformers

I have a code that is supposed to do these things:

Load already trained model
Load an unseen dataset
Create a pipeline which takes Bert encoder (SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')) and my trained model.
Then randomly choose a row from dataset, encode it, and predict it
Then ask if the prediction is correct. If not, then ask for the correct prediction and retrain the model with the right prediction

I am using this code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, models

# Load the trained model
multi_model = joblib.load(filename)


# Load the dataset

# Create a pipeline using the SentenceTransformer and the trained model
bert_model = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')
pipeline = Pipeline([('encoder', bert_model), ('classifier', multi_model)])

# Choose a random row from the dataset
random_row = full_df.sample(1)
X = random_row[['mmgid', 'body','preprocessedBody']]  # select specific columns
article = np.random.choice(X['preprocessedBody'])
print("working")
# Encode the article and make a prediction
encoded_text = bert_model.encode([article])
print("working")

prediction = pipeline.predict([encoded_text])[0]
print("working")

print(X['mmgid'])
print(X['body'])
print(f"Prediction: {prediction}")

# Ask the user if the prediction is correct
response = input("Is this prediction correct? (yes/no)")

# If the prediction is incorrect, ask the user for the correct classification
if response.lower() == 'no':
    correct_classification = input("What is the correct classification for this article?")
    
    # Retrain the model using the original article and the correct classification
    pipeline.fit([(encoded_text)[0]], [correct_classification])

    # Test the updated model by classifying the same article again
    updated_prediction = pipeline.predict([encoded_text[0]])

    # Display the new prediction to the user
    print(f"The updated model predicts that this article belongs to the '{updated_prediction}' category.")
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformer' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Where do you use the transform attribute, did you write all the code?

Comment: Yes it is the complete code